# How to handle undelimited multirow headers in .txt table

Tags: python, string

I'm trying to import and process tables with headers that sometimes have multiple rows in *some* columns:

```
                                                                                         DFA Real
                                                                                          Estate     Large Cap
                                                             U.S. Small    U.S. Micro   Securities International
                                                            Cap Portfolio Cap Portfolio Portfolio    Portfolio
```

I'm having trouble combining the rows in each (undelimited) column in the header to one item (e.g. "U.S. Small Cap Portfolio", "U.S. Micro Cap Portfolio", etc.).

What could be a good and robust solution?

Comment: And based on what would you determine what constitutes the same header? Can you differentiate header rows from the other rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since all the headers are aligned with an invisible space as a border, you can simply find these common spaces and use them to divide the lines into respective headers.

First pad the lines to the width of the longest line, then find the common positions of spaces among all the lines of the header, slice the lines according to these positions, and finally reassemble the slices where strings aren't just white spaces.

```
from functools import reduce
header='''
                                                                                             DFA Real
                                                                                              Estate     Large Cap
                                                                 U.S. Small    U.S. Micro   Securities International
                                                                Cap Portfolio Cap Portfolio Portfolio    Portfolio'''
lines = header.split('\n')
width = max(map(len, lines))
lines = [l + ' ' * (width - len(l)) for l in lines]
borders = list(reduce(set.intersection, [{i for i, c in enumerate(l) if c == ' '} for l in lines]))
print([' '.join(h).strip() for h in zip(*[[l[b:e].strip() for b, e in zip(borders[:-1], borders[1:])] for l in lines]) if any(h)])
```

This outputs:

```
['U.S. Small Cap Portfolio', 'U.S. Micro Cap Portfolio', 'DFA Real Estate Securities Portfolio']
```

Comment: That answer you just posted (not this one) is for a troll question. Be careful how you spend your time there. He's screwing with you.